# How to get reports from testcafe docker image?

Tags: docker, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I created an docker image based on the testcafe image.

But the xunit and html reports are not being generated, is there some way of doing it?

`FROM testcafe/testcafe

USER root

RUN npm install -g testcafe-reporter-xunit
RUN npm install -g testcafe-reporter-html

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json /app
COPY ./ /app

CMD ["chromium:headless --no-sandbox", "--reporter xunit:reports/jReport.xml,html:reports/report.html"]`

If I do a top inside the container looks like the command is correct:

`/bin/sh /opt/testcafe/docker/testcafe-docker.sh chromium:headless --no-sandbox --reporter xunit:reports/jReport.xml,html:reports/report.html`

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the issue.
I created my own image based on your file (except the WORKDIR part).
Then I executed the following command: `docker run -v //c/Users/User/testcafe-docker/tests:/tests1 -it --entrypoint /bin/sh alexkamaev/myimage` to run an interactive shell.
Then I ran `/opt/testcafe/docker/testcafe-docker.sh chromium:headless --no-sandbox --reporter xunit:/tests1/xReport.xml,html:/tests1/report.html` as you described.
And then I checked that the files exist using the following commands: `cd tests1` and `ls`. The `ls` shows me that my files were created successfully.

Comment: Could you try to follow these steps using your image?